# Counting number of states for fermions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, approximations

I have a system of $N$ fermions that can occupy $M$ single particle states, and $M$ is much larger than $N$, $M \gg N$. Since only a single or no fermion can be in a particular state, the number of way of counting the number of states for indistinguishable fermions is going to simply be ${M \choose N}$. This means that the number of states $n$, is
\begin{align*}
n &= {M\choose N} \\ 
&= \frac{M!}{(M-N)!N!}
\end{align*}
Using Stirling's approximation,
\begin{align*}
n &= \frac{(M/e)^M}{\left((M-N)/e\right)^{M-N}(N/e)^N} \\
&= \frac{M^M}{(M-N)^{M-N}N^N} = \frac{M^M}{(1-N/M)^{M-N} \cdot M^{M-N}N^N} \\
&= \left(\frac{M}{N} \right) ^N \cdot \left( 1-\frac{N}{M} \right)^{N-M} \\
&\implies \boxed{n =  \left(\frac{M}{N} \right) ^N \cdot \left( 1-\frac{N}{M} \right)^{N-M} }
\end{align*}

Does this process make sense? Am I using the approximation right?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be strictly a math question..

Comment: I think you are, although a slightly rougher approximation is usually used to emphasize the connection with the classical number  $M^N/N!$

Comment: @AlekseyDruggist what is that rougher approximation? I also realized that $N!$ should not be approximated

Comment: @megamence, use Stirling's approximation: $N!≈N^Nexp(-N)$